# In py.test, when I explicitly skip a test that is marked as xfail, how can I get it reported as 'skipped' instead of 'xfailed'?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a py.test test function marked as xfail:

```
@pytest.mark.xfail
def test_that_fails():
    assert 1 == 2
```

In my pytest_runtest_setup() hook, I skip this test explicitly:

```
def pytest_runtest_setup (item):
    pytest.skip ('Skipping this test')
```

When I run py.test, it reports that the test xfailed:

```
tests.py x

========================== 1 xfailed in 1.69 seconds ===========================
```

How can I get py.test to report this test as skipped?

It seems like I am asking, "How can I remove the xfail marking form this test in my pytest_runtest_setup() hook?"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the bug report :)

I agree that expecting py.test to report this as a "skipped" tests rather than xfail makes sense.  After all, the xfail-outcome (xfail/xpass) cannot be determined if the test is skipped. I just fixed this issue which you can install by typing:

```
pip_install -i http://pypi.testrun.org -U pytest
# using easy_install is fine as well
```

this should get you 2.2.5.dev4 with "py.test --version" and fix your issue. It will be part of the next pypi release.